# Discord.js 13 mention user in MessageEmbed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am currently working on a welcome embed functionality for my Discord bot.

But I am having trouble mentioning a user.

I tried every method I found but they all seem to be for previous versions of discord.js

Here is the code I used

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    member.guild.channels.get('channelID').send({
      title: 'We got a new user',
      description: 'Welcome <mention>'
    }]
  }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can mention, but not *ping* (send a notification) in embeds. Secondly, you have to put it in the `embeds` property

```js
member.guild.channels.get('channelID').send({
    embeds: [{
        title: "We got a new user",
        description: `Welcome ${member}`
    }]
})
```

You can use the `member.toString()` method to get the mention. It's already called in template literals, so you don't have to put the `.toString()` yourself. Another way is `<@${member.id}>`. Note that `embeds` is an array

Answer (score -1):

```
const embed = new MessageEmbed()
.setTitle('We got a new user')
.setDescription(`Welcome <@${member.id}>`)

bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    member.guild.channels.cache.get('channelID').send({
      embeds: [embed] 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Code only answers are not good. Please provide an explanation. Another thing is that this won't work since `member` will be `undefined` in that scope

Comment: Downvoted as `member.id` is not available outside of the callback of the `guildMemberAdd` listener.